# What does the phrase 'in the enterprise' mean?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, phrases, prepositional-phrases, terminology

I saw it in the title of a [book](https://books.google.hu/books?id=wBVrDQAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&hl=it#v=onepage&q&f=false).

My guess would be "on an enterprise level", is that correct or does it convey something more than that?

Edit:
I can understand what an enterprise is, but why is it used with a definite article and in singular form? Why isn't the book called "Starting and Scaling DevOps in enterprises"? The book is definitely not written about a specific enterprise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An "enterprise" is generally a business or other endeavor, especially a money-making endeavor.

In technology, it takes on a specific meaning: the hardware, software, and practices associated with running the IT backbone of a business, especially a large business.  This is in contrast to software and practices associated with home users.

edit: "in the enterprise" means in the enterprise *environment*. There is only one enterprise environment, though there may be many enterprises.

Comment: Added an edit to reflect on your answer.

Comment: Thank you for providing more information about the specific phrase. Can this kind of phrasing only be used with the word "enterprise" or in other cases too?

Comment: There are other cases too.  The first example that come to mind is also IT related.  Such as "working in the cloud," referring to a cloud environment, not a particular cloud.

Comment: Yes, indeed. I have seen that example many times, but not the one in my question. Thanks again, I will remember this pattern.